# No wi-fi on Ubuntu 14.04 with Intel

Tags: 14.04, drivers, wireless, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I'm a total noob at Ubuntu so I've come for help. I have to use ubuntu 14.04 for my work, which obviously is not ideal as it's a bit outdated, and I can't get wi-fi to work. I'm 95% sure I'm missing the drivers I need, but I'm not sure if I'd even be able to get them to work with trusty.

I have a Dell G5 5587. `lspci` gives me `00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device a370 (rev 10)`.
I've searched for what this means but to no avail - I think G5's like mine generally come with intel 9560, but I can't figure out how to verify this on my own machine.

Other info:
The (wi-fi related) output for `sudo lshw -C network` is:

```
      *-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   version: 10
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:ed3a4000-ed3a7fff
```

`rfkill list all` gives me no output at all.
`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` gives me:

```
    00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a370] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4030]
    00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a368] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0824]
```

`sudo modprobe wl` returns not found.

`dmesg | grep -i firmware` returns

```
    [    0.245032] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
```

Here's the output of just `dmesg`: https://pastebin.com/BqJ2kexC

Where do I go from here? I don't even know what drivers to look for, or if they'll be compatible with 14.04. Any advice would be great.

Comment: hello, how about linux firmware package, it is installed? to check out which module is currently load for a specific device perform this command: 'sudo lspci -s 00:14.3 -vv' at the end of the output have two line kernel driver in use and kernel modules; Also in the dmesg you get a lot of error messages (also that says firmware bug) should be checked out, by reconfigure bios, update at least the kernel and as last solution try to disable acpi by adding in the grub string acpi=off

Answer (score 0):

In short, the driver version in Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't yet cover your very new wireless device.

You are in the classic dilemma, a very new device with an older kernel version, 4.4.0-xx, and its associated driver. While it is possible to search and find by trial and error, a downloadable, compilable from source code driver and install it, it is much easier to download the iso for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS which contains the later 4.15.0-33 kernel and linux-firmware and for which I confirm covers your 8086:a370 device.

http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/

Try the live session USB or DVD and when you’ve confirmed that the wireless works as expected, install it.